# Why doesn't 'cp /user/local' work?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory, cp

I was trying to copy a directory to `/user/bin` (on Ubuntu 12.04). I tells me that I ``` cannot create directory ``/user/local' ``` No such file or directory`. Where did I make a mistake?

```
sudo cp -r apache-maven /user/local/
cp: cannot create directory `/user/local': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Appears there is a typo. The name of the directory is **/usr/local**, not /user/local. Can you try the first path name instead?

Comment: This is actually a good question, considering that we pronounce "usr" as "user".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/user/*` is not a valid directory within a normal Linux system. It is `/usr/`. So ...

```
sudo cp -r apache-maven /usr/local/
```

can be valid. Though I probably would put maven into `/opt/` myself.